# Proper error handling and response in react with express and Mongoose

Tags: javascript

```
    // delete function
    delete =(index) => {
      const st = this.state.data;
      const newSt = st[index]._id;

      // fetch delete api

      fetch(`http://localhost:4000/users/${newSt}`, {
        method: 'DELETE'
       }, (err,result) => {
           if(err){
               console.log(err)
        }else{
          result.json({'msg': 'ok'})
        }
      })
      st.splice(index,1)
      this.setState({data: st})
  }
```

I just created a delete function for my react-express-mongoose app. but the (err,result) isnt working. What did I do wrong? (the delete function works) I am just confused about the {(err,result) => {...} and what should I do inside it.

Comment: hello kathmandu. please makes sure that you followed the following usage synopsis for fetch() function.
fetch(url, options).then(function(response) {
  // handle HTTP response
}, function(error) {
  // handle network error
})

Answer (score 0):

I believe fetch is a promise so it needs the following syntax

```
fetch(opts)
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

[Fetch API: Using Fetch](http://devdocs.io/dom/fetch_api/using_fetch)

Answer (score 0):

Please make your function like the following structure.

```
// delete function
    delete =(index) => {
      const st = this.state.data;
      const newSt = st[index]._id;

      // fetch delete api

      fetch(`http://localhost:4000/users/${newSt}`, {method: 'DELETE'}).then((res) => { console.log(res); })
           , (err,result) => {
           if(err){
               console.log(err)
        }else{
          result.json({'msg': 'ok'})
        }
      })
      st.splice(index,1)
      this.setState({data: st})
  }
```